The topology on Riemmanian manifolds as metric space
Let $M$ be a smooth manifold (no hypothesis on $M$ are done e.g. compactness or connectedness), then given $g_1$ and $g_2$ Riemmanian metric on $M$ we can see $M$ as a metric space with the distance:\begin{align}
d(p,q)=inf\{\ell(c):\text{$c$ is a smooth curve connecting $p$ and $q$}\}.
\end{align}
Now consider the distance $d_1$ and $d_2$ induced by $g_1$ and $g_2$ respectively.
My question are:
$(1)$ The topology of $(M,d_1)$ and $(M,d_2)$ is the same as the topology of M as a manifold?
$(2)$ If yes, then any two metrics on $M$ induces, as a metric space, the same topology?
I think that $(1)$ should be false, otherwise we can't have a complete metric and a non complete metric on the same manifold, but this phenomena clearly happens.
I also think that the connectedness of $M$ should be crucial but i can't see why.
Any help or reference is well accepted. Thanks.

How do you have a metric space if $M$ is disconnected?

the answer to (1) is yes; there is no such notion as a "complete topological space", so no contradiction arises (there are complete metric spaces and complete uniformity spaces)

This is covered in any Riemannian geometry textbook. I suggest you read one. There are many suggestions on this site.

@Ted: you get an extended metric by setting the distance to $\infty$ if two points are in different connected components. This is a pretty harmless generalization of metric spaces and it endows the category of metric spaces (and short maps) with coproducts given by infinitely distant disjoint unions.


Yes, any two Riemannian metrics induce the Euclidean topology. I am not familiar enough with Riemannian geometry to offer a rigorous proof but here's a sketch. This is a purely local question: the question of what topology a metric induces depends only on the behavior of arbitrarily small balls, and once the balls get small enough they can be described in local coordinates and become arbitrarily close to being balls in the tangent spaces, so we can reduce to the familiar fact that any inner product induces the Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$. This does not contradict the fact that some metrics are complete and some are incomplete, because completeness is not a topological property.

The word "metric" in this question is ambiguous. Yes, any two Riemannian metrics induce the same topology, as we've just seen, and of course the same is not true for arbitrary metrics, e.g. the discrete metric.


As I mentioned in the comments, connectedness is irrelevant if you slightly generalize metric spaces to extended metrics which can take the value $\infty$; then this becomes the distance between two points in different connected components. Again, the topology induced by a metric only depends on the behavior of arbitrarily small balls, so this doesn't make a difference to the induced topology.
